# jMimeMagic returning mime type for docx, pptx, jar files as application/zip

Tags: mime-types

I read the mimetype for .docx file is application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document. But when I upload a .docx file(one that I just created, not from a zip file) and check for its mimetype in my application using

```
String mimeType = Magic.getMagicMatch(file1, false).getMimeType();
```

I get Mimetype as application/zip.
I get the same result when I try to upload a .jar file.
I mean this way, how can I check if the user is uploading a msword or a jar file to my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the .*x Office variants (.docx, .pptx, and so on) are XML-based content which is wrapped in a ZIP "container" to keep them compact, and your library is detecting the ZIP header correctly but then either not checking for, or failing to find, the additional information that would allow it to distinguish those from a ZIP file containing whatever random data someone put into it.

Similarly, the JAR file format is an extension of the ZIP file format, so if the library does not know to check for the "special type of ZIP" case, it would simply report it as a ZIP file.